# Unable to boot Windows 8 after an interrupted Ubuntu installation attempt

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, boot, grub

I have a Sony Vaio notebook with Windows 8(UEFI) installed,after trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS(I cancelled the installation and restarted the pc) from a usb sticky,every time i turn on the computer a GNU GRUB bash show up.I can't figure it out how boot Windows again!

So,resuming:

How can i boot Windows(or at least the UEFI menu) from the gnu grub bash?

Note:I already tried to hold/press repeatedly(F2,ESC,SHIFT,...) keys but nothing worked.

Image of the screen:

[image]

Comment: How far were you in the installation when you cancelled? Also, had you selected to "use the entire disk" or to "install side-by-side with windows"?

Comment: I selected the 'Something else' option,then realized that i had forgotten to split the hard drive while i still in Windows(as i seen on a tutorial).

Comment: But you did not actually proceed with altering the drives?

Comment: No,i clicked the cancel installation option and then Ubuntu loaded,then i clicked to reboot,in order to boot on Windows again

Comment: Hm. That is odd. Make sure the installation media is removed, but either way it shouldn't affect this. If you had not selected a drive option, it should not have installed grub yet. Whereas, this looks to be an incomplete installation to me.

Comment: I had installed Ubuntu 13.10 before and then removed from the hard drive in order to install 12.04

Comment: Were you able to boot into windows after the 13.10 installation, or had you not tried?

Comment: Yes,several times.

Comment: Not to be redundant, but including after you removed 13.10? Just want to be sure.

Comment: Perhaps its related,when i began to install Ubuntu 12.04 i marked the option to 'download the latests updates'

Comment: That option only has an effect on the install process. While it is installing the OS, it will include the updates so that you don't have to update as soon as you boot up.

Comment: No,after i removed the 13.10 i created the 12.04 boot image on the pen-drive and proceed to install Ubuntu,so i didn't boot on windows after that

Comment: I don't mind losing all my files,i just want to be able to boot on windows again,do you know if there's a way to format every thing and install Windows again?

Comment: Aha! yes. Actually, with the UEFI your windows 8 key is already in your BIOS! So, if you simply get a windows 8 disk that is the same as the version you have, it won't even ask for the key. Just boot to disk and wipe it all.

Comment: The problem is that i can't access the BIOS!

Comment: If i put a Windows installation cd the computer will show up a different screen?The BIOS(uefi menu)?

Comment: Before this problem i was holding the SHIFT key in order to display the UEFI menu,but when i hold it now nothing happens!

Comment: Are you able to boot to a disk? Sorry, I lost my place there for a moment haha. I got too excited without remembering the important stuff

Comment: I don't have a disk(it didn't come when i bought the pc),i will have to download and pass to a disk.As i believe Windows still installed on the machine i thought that there were some way to boot from it

Answer (score 1):

As we were speaking in comments, I decided to post this here. The error is saying you need to load the kernel. This is a page I found that details manually loading the kernel, using the grub terminal. (Which, obviously is what you are looking at)

[Loading the Kernel](https://www.suse.com/communities/conversations/loading-linux-kernel-manually-using-grub-sles/)

Comment: Thanks for the help,but i could't manage to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a problem with the boot loader (currently Grub). Try re-installing Grub from the Ubuntu live CD. I would recommend the utility [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

If you are not going to use Linux anyways (or you would like to have the Ubuntu install CD simply reinstall Grub), you could restore the Windows boot loader from the Windows recovery CD (you kept it around right?). I'm not an expert on Windows so look at [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee851681.aspx) article for help.